# $a,b$ integral $\implies$ $a+b$ integral

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm sure it's just silly thing. I'm reading Fulton's algebraic curves book and I don't understand this phrase of this proof:

[image]

I didn't understand why according to the proposition we have $a\pm b,ab$ integral over $R$.

**Proposition**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the proposition, take $R' := R[a, b]$ to be the subring containing $R[a + b]$ (or $R[ab]$).